# trying to write easy diff script to compare 2 file then mv them to a directory

Tags: linux, shell-script

This is what I have: trying to compare 2 files, if the same files to move them to a directory name `host.bk`

```
#!/bin/sh

if 'diff $file1 $file2 >/dev/null' ; then

mv $file1 $file2 host.bk

else
  echo Different
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

`if` takes an arbitrary command, so you can just use `diff` without any quoting or command substitution. Also, we could use the `-q` flag to inhibit the output.

```
if diff -q "$file1" "$file2" ; then
    echo "files $file1 and $file2 contain identical data"
else
    echo files differ (or an error happened)
fi
```

Comment: `cmp` is more efficient than `diff` because it doesn't care what the differences are, only that they exist. So `if cmp -s "$file1" "$file2"; then echo same; fi`

Comment: if the file are the same, i need to move them to a specific directory.can I just add a line with mv ?

Comment: still  not working,,,

this what I have:
#!/bin/sh

if diff "$file1" "$file2" &>/dev/null ; then


echo "mv $file2 hosts.bk" alreay moved second file to its directory


else
    echo files differ
fi

the output is always "files differ" it is seems not taking the first condition data

Answer (score 2):

Use `cmp` for when the actual difference between the files is not needed:

```
if cmp -s "$file1" $file2"; then
  printf '"%s" and "%s" are the same, moving...\n' "$file1" $file2"
  mv "$file1" $file2" host.bk/
else
  printf '"%s" and "%s" are different\n' "$file1" $file2"
fi
```